# React App goes blank after importing React-Router-Dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Before importing `react-router` it was working fine. Now it build successfully but shows a blank page. Here is my code:

App.js

```
//import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import  'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Pending from './Pages/Home';
import Home from './Pages/Pending';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={Home} />
        <Route path="/Pending" element={Pending} />  
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';

function Home(){
  return(
    <div>
      <div>
        <NavBar/>
      </div>
      <h1>HI</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 4):

## Issue

The `Route` component API changed in `react-router-dom@6`. All routed content is now rendered on a single `element` prop as a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, not a reference to a React component.

## Solution

Render the routed components as JSX, i.e. `<Home />` instead of `Home`.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Pending from './Pages/Home';
import Home from './Pages/Pending';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/Pending" element={<Pending />} /> 
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*You should specify which version of react-router-dom you are using. So I'm just gonna assume, you are using the latest v6.*

In your `App.js` file, you have to make the following changes in order to work:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import  'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Pending from './Pages/Home';
import Home from './Pages/Pending';
    
    export default function App() {
          return (
             <Routes>
               <Route index path="/" element={<Home />}/>
                  <Route path="pending" element={<Pending />} />  
             </Routes>
          );
    }
```

For more info, please visit the official documentation [here!](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

Answer (score 0):

```
import './App.css';

import {   BrowserRouter as Router ,  Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';

import Home from './Components/Home';
import About from './Components/About';


function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Header/>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={ <Home/> } />
            <Route path="/About" element={ <About/> } />
        </Routes>
      <Footer/>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think you should provide some answer to your code as well. Just copy pasting a code, which not even related to the question, it's hard to understand. Also, as you only have one element inside your App, you don't need to use React.Fragment <>, you use fragment, when you have multiple children, as react only renders one.